# Reload Image using picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm using picasso to load url image to my image view.The image will change within the same url so added a refresh button to reload the new image. any help?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    Picasso.with(this).load("http://xxxxx/cgi-bin/video.JPG").into(v);

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
   else if(id==R.id.refresh){
   onResume();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I added this line and it's working fine now.

`Picasso.with(this).invalidate();`